# What does return (Object) null mean in c#?

Tags: c#, return

New to C#, and I'm reviewing some code that has the following return statement:

```
return (Object) null
```

What does this mean in C#, what will be returned ?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably pointless. What's the method in which you found this line?

Comment: IMHO, this is the same as `return null;`...

Comment: @Mr_Green: dispose of what?  There's nothing to dispose!

Comment: I can't show the method unfortunately as it is very confidential code ! :)

Comment: Does this mean that someone likes writing a confusing and not readable code? :)

Comment: @Relax_Im_A_Quant "as it is very confidential code" - yes, but it usually fine to put together a small sample using invented unrelated types (`Customer`, `Order`, `Person` are all good innocent type names), that shows the usage/scenario without putting your real code on show

Comment: I am actually using a decompiler to read this code, and I can see this kid of return statement throughout, could it be to do with decompilation ?

Comment: @Relax It could well be an artifact of the decompiler, yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only place I can think of where this is required is in an anonymous method where the compiler can't infer the return type.

For example,

```
var boxedThings = strings.Select(s =>
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
        return i;
    double d;
    if (double.TryParse(s, out d))
        return d;
    return (object)null;
});
```

doesn't compile without the `(object)`.

Comment: ooh, nice; generic type inference from the return type - I didn't think of that one

Answer (score 6):

It is absolutely equal to `return null`

Comment: Well, not *absolutely* equal (I can think of plenty of places where `return null;` would work, and `return (Object) null;` would not compile) - but *semantically*, yes - they mean the same

Comment: Thanks Kirill - if possible can you explain the benefit of returning null in this way ?

Comment: I can think of places where `return null` doesn't work and `return (object)null` _does_, but they're pretty dumb places.

Comment: @Relax_Im_A_Quant there are none

Comment: @Relax_Im_A_Quant, there is no possible benefits from using return (Object)null; I think it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting an Object which has a null value.